# jhipster generated app works fine without yarn start, by simply on 8080, so why to run on port 9000

Tags: npm, jhipster, yarnpkg

jhipster's readme file says
Run the following commands in two separate terminals 
    ./mvnw
    yarn start

I accidentally , only ran ./mvnw ( that runs spring-boot:run ) and my app runs fine on port 8080. The question is, what is the purpose of running it on port 9000 with yarn start, I am not a UI Developer.

Comment: So in a team environment if middleware team is developing and making java code change, they need not run the application on 9000 ( yarn start) . But the UI team should run on both ports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JHipster uses the **port 9000 for the client-side code**.
If you make changes to your Angular code, you will be able to see the results directly thanks to ***BrowserSync***.

> "*This provides very impressive features:*
>
> *As soon as you modify one of your HTML/CSS/TypeScript file, your
>   browser will refresh itself automatically*
>
> *When you test your application on several different browsers or devices, all your
>   clicks/scrolls/inputs should be automatically synchronized on all
>   screens*"
>
> http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular

If the app is not running on port 9000, I don't think you will see any client-side change, on port 8080.